# how to download apt-get update files to use later on with offline machine?

Tags: linux, debian, apt, package-management, upgrade

Is there any way to download apt-get update files so that later on I can use `apt-get update --no-download` option. I have tried -d while updating first but since all packages are already installed and only updated -d wont work. I need to download these packages: You may give me alternate solution of downloading this debian files. That would be ok. All I need is this files downloaded on a dir.

`Get:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease [39.1 kB] 
Get:2 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main amd64 Packages [113 kB] 
Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease [122 kB] 
Get:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease [49.3 kB] Get:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 Packages [7899 kB] Get:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates/main amd64 Packages [5792 B]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think `--no-download` is meant to be used with `update`, it might be ignored. If you have an online machine running Debian, it stores the files it downloads/updates with `apt update` in `/var/lib/apt/lists`, you can try copying that to your offline machine, but I have no idea if that will do anything marginally useful. But they are mostly useful in finding out where to download each package, which you won't be able to on an offline machine, so that's probably not what you want.

The actual packages are stored in `/var/cache/apt/archives`.

I believe there are solutions for keeping Debian machines updated offline, but I've never tried them.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Copying `/var/lib/apt/lists` this to my offline computer's location worked fine. That was the solution that I seeked.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking about is a fairly common issue with several solutions having been developed over the years. I've used the following three separate tools on various occasions - all worked well for me at the time, so I have no preference. All are available in the debian repositories and have ample documentation.

1. apt-offline
2. reprepro
3. apt-cacher-ng